# Android object persistance: Ektorp and CouchDB

Tags: android, couchdb, object-persistence

Hi: Has someone experience with object persistence on Android by using [ektorp](http://code.google.com/p/ektorp/) and CouchDB? Including the 'Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)' [jar](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) is necessary to try this out.

I tried to get it running but I still get a 'java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError' because of 'ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2573): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbInstance$1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialization of the CouchDbInstance fails where it references a type from the Jackson library.

Make sure you have Jackson on your classpath.

Comment: And use the jackson 1.7.7. Version because Ektopr is not compatible with newer ones.

Comment: Ektorp 1.2.0 which is due soon will be compatible with newer Jackson releases